# Is there a way to find the algorithm of a string to use to generate more strings of same algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, generate

I have a string of 43 characters. Example: azZZRzqw4ziDlBWkpqgbOtLHZvThSM99Hw3cCEDxwJM

I want to know if it is possible to get their algorithms and generate a different string with the same algorithm in the initial given string.

Like serial keys, i want to know if i can generate a different string with the same algorithm that can be used for the same purpose as the earlier string.

Comment: Probably not. If the string was generated using an encryption and a secret key you would need to break the encryption in order to be able to keep generating strings.

Comment: From where is that "example" you gave? Is this the full example? A cookie?

Comment: No, the example is like a serial key that makes an application run. So how do i get the algorithm used to generate that key?